# IMPORTANT: Remember to use the included executable `certifed-update` regularly to keep your certificate bundle up to date

Tags: ruby, rubygems

```
$ gem install bundler
```

gives me (at the end of the successful install):

```
Post-install message from certified:
IMPORTANT: Remember to use the included executable `certifed-update` regularly to keep your certificate bundle up to date.
```

I can't see how I'm going to remember to keep this executable indefinitely up to date. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in the message: `certifed-update` does not exist, it's `certified-update` (notice the missing "i"). It's strange as this typo is [fixed](https://github.com/stevegraham/certified/commit/fb9ec7ee6d7451b836c5103a72558a0ee071f434) in latest gem code (maybe the author forgot to publish a new version, who knows)

You can run this tool manually with:

```
bundle exec certified-update
```

Which yields this message:

> Updating ca-bundle from
>   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bagder/ca-bundle/master/ca-bundle.crt
>   Certificate bundle updated. Remember to do this regularly!

In order to remember to update the certificates you can configure a periodic reminder in your calendar, or you can setup a cron job or similar to make it automatically ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using [this gem](https://github.com/stevegraham/certified) and it's getting run somehow after `gem install bundler`. Try deleting it via `gem uninstall certified` and rerun `gem install bundler`.